# Fast Parquet row count in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

The Parquet files contain a per-block row count field. Spark seems to read it at some point ([`SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.java#L151`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.2/sql/core/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/parquet/SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.java#L151)).

I tried this in `spark-shell`:

```
sqlContext.read.load("x.parquet").count
```

And Spark ran two stages, showing various aggregation steps in the DAG. I figure this means it reads through the file normally instead of using the row counts. (I could be wrong.)

The question is: Is Spark already using the row count fields when I run `count`? Is there another API to use those fields? Is relying on those fields a bad idea for some reason?

Answer (score 20):

That is correct, Spark is already using the rowcounts field when you are running `count`.

Diving into the details a bit, the [SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.java](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.2/sql/core/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/parquet/SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.java#L151) references the [Improve Parquet scan performance when using flat schemas commit](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/cfdd8a1a304d66f2a424800ccc026874e6c5f1a8) as part of [[SPARK-11787] Speed up parquet reader for flat schemas](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11787).  Note, this commit was included as part of the Spark 1.6 branch.

If the query is a row count, it pretty much works the way you described it (i.e. reading the metadata).  If the predicates are fully satisfied by the min/max values, that *should* work as well though that is not as fully verified.  It's not a bad idea to use those Parquet fields but as implied in the previous statement, the key issue is to ensure that the predicate filtering matches the metadata so you are doing an accurate count.

To help understand why there are two stages, here's the DAG created when running the count() statement.

[image]

When digging into the two stages, notice that the first one (Stage 25) is running the file scan while the second stage (Stage 26) runs the shuffle for the count.

[image]
[image]

Thanks to Nong Li (the author of the [SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.java](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.2/sql/core/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/parquet/SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.java#L151) commit) for validating!

#### Updated

To provide additional context on the bridge between `Dataset.count` and Parquet, the flow of the internal logic surrounding this is:

- Spark does not read any Parquet columns to calculate the count
- Passing of the Parquet schema to the `VectorizedParquetRecordReader` is actually an empty Parquet message
- Computing the count using the metadata stored in the Parquet file footers.
  involves the wrapping of the above within an iterator that returns an `InternalRow` per [InternalRow.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/InternalRow.scala).

To work with the Parquet File format, internally, Apache Spark wraps the logic with an iterator that returns an `InternalRow`; more information can be found in [InternalRow.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/InternalRow.scala). Ultimately, the `count()` aggregate function interacts with the underlying Parquet data source using this iterator. BTW, this is true for both vectorized and non-vectorized Parquet reader.

Therefore, to bridge the `Dataset.count()` with the Parquet reader, the path is:

- The `Dataset.count()` call is planned into an aggregate operator with a single count() aggregate function.
- Java code is generated at planning time for the aggregate operator as well as the count() aggregate function.
- The generated Java code interacts with the underlying data source ParquetFileFormat with an RecordReaderIterator, which is used internally by the Spark data source API.

For more information, please refer to [Parquet Count Metadata Explanation](https://github.com/dennyglee/databricks/blob/master/misc/parquet-count-metadata-explanation.md).

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer! When you say _"it pretty much works the way you described it"_ do you mean it does a scan through the file, or does it look at the metadata in the Parquet file? (I'm afraid I described both possibilities in the question...) Same goes for the _"That is correct"_ at the start :). Thanks for any clarification!

Comment: Sorry about that - I meant that it reads the metadata of the Parquet file. I'll edit the answer shortly.  :).

Comment: Thank you for a nice answer but I am not convinced yet. You are linking to `totalRowCount` but it looks like it is used only by `getProgress()`, `checkEndOfRowGroups()` and `nextBatch()` and I cannot find any package level access. Could you add a reference how it is used with combination with `Dataset.count`. TIA

Comment: Good point - I thought I had tracked it down correctly but I may be missing something.  Here's the path from `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet` in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/dennyglee/d427594b3a0a58890631e9b020418625) - does this look right?

Comment: I am not sure. It looks like the thing that could be used but I still cannot figure out if it is or not. Not enough understanding on my side :(

Comment: Just updated my response which hopefully helps address the bridge between ParquetFileFormat and `dataset.count()`.  HTH!

Answer (score -1):

We can also use

java.text.NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance.format(sparkdf.count)