# Why dataset.count() is faster than rdd.count()?

Tags: scala, performance, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I created a Spark `Dataset[Long]`:

```
scala> val ds = spark.range(100000000)
ds: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Long] = [id: bigint]
```

When I ran `ds.count` it gave me result in `0.2s` (on a 4 Core 8GB machine). Also, the DAG it created is as follows:

[image]

But, when I ran `ds.rdd.count` it gave me result in `4s` (same machine). But the DAG it created is as follows:

[image]

So, my doubts are:

1. Why `ds.rdd.count` is creating only one stage whereas `ds.count` is creating 2 stages ?
2. Also, when `ds.rdd.count` is having only one stage then why it is slower than `ds.count` which has 2 stages ?

Comment: AFAIK `ds.rdd.count` is very slow because the entire dataset is evaluated (i.e. all columns of all rows) although this not really necessary just to get the number of rows. Dataset/Dataframe API optimises this query considerable (see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714291/how-to-force-dataframe-evaluation-in-spark)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why ds.rdd.count is creating only one stage whereas ds.count is creating 2 stages ?

Both counts are effectively two step operations. The difference is that in case of `ds.count`, the final aggregation is performed by one of the executors, while `ds.rdd.count`[aggregates the final result on the driver](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0a7f5f2798b6e8b2ba15e8b3aa07d5953ad1c695/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L1158), therefore this step is not reflected in the DAG:

> Also, when `ds.rdd.count` is having only one stage then why it is slower

Ditto. Moreover `ds.rdd.count` has to initialize (and later garbage collect) 100 million `Row` objects, what is hardly free and probably accounts for majority of the time difference here.

Finally `range`-like objects are not a good benchmarking tool, unless used with a lot of caution. Depending on the context count over range can be expressed as a constant time operation and even without explicit optimizations can be extremely fast (see for example `spark.sparkContext.range(0, 100000000).count`) but don't reflect performance with a real workload.

Related to: [How to know which count query is the fastest?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43843470/6910411)

Comment: Thanks for response! It is a nice explanation of my question. And thanks for the suggestion too about `spark.sparkContext.range(0, 100000000).count`. It actually works. But my real issue was creating nested JSON files with Spark SQL. With Spark Dataset I can do it fast, but with RDD its a real pain !

Comment: Related question: is my understanding correct and rdd.count will run a distributed job, however ds.count will bring all data to a driver? To answer my own question: its not true :)

Answer (score 1):

**New in spark 3.3.0**

```
pyspark.sql.DataFrame.isEmpty
```

> Returns True if this DataFrame is empty.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.isEmpty.html