# Check if number of records in dataframe is greater than zero without using count spark

Tags: apache-spark

I want to check if my created dataframe is not empty and has at least 1 record. Is there any better approach other than using **count** method and checking if the count value is greater than 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `rdd.isEmpty`:

```
scala> Seq[(Long, String)]((1L, "a")).toDF.rdd.isEmpty
res0: Boolean = false

scala> Seq[(Long, String)]().toDF.rdd.isEmpty
```

res1: Boolean = true

Comment: Will that be faster than count?

Answer (score 4):

Might as well do this:

```
df.take(1).length == 0
```

`rdd.isEmpty` implements the above functionality internally.

Comment: It can be even faster. When we're calling `.rdd`, Spark is not able to optimize query for some datasources, i.e. JDBC. Your version uses all optmizations that are possible

Comment: @T.Gawęda Aren't RDDs the underlying sources of everything in Spark? I'm just wondering will `df.rdd` take a lot of time if the dataframe has, say, a million rows?

Comment: It is used by Datasets, but when you invoke action on Dataset, when Spark tries to optimize query. Also, call to `rdd` deserializes Rows from internal form to normal - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43843470/how-to-know-which-count-query-is-the-fastest

Answer (score 0):

Use isEmpty of RDD

```
def isEmpty(): Boolean = withScope {
partitions.length == 0 || take(1).length == 0
```

}