# What is the faster way to count the number of entries in a data frame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame `df` that contains around 1 Gb of data. Why the command `df.count()` takes a relatively long time to complete, while `df.filter(...)` is much faster? Is there any better way to estimate the number of entries in `df` that is faster than `df.count()`'

Comment: Without iterating the DF, how do you find the count? and what do you mean by df.filter is faster? filter is totally for different purpose.

Comment: @Shankar: If I correctly understand your first question, `df.count()` returns me the number of rows in `df`. As to your second question, I know that both commands serve for different purposes. I put `filter` as an example. I just want to know why `df.count()` takes 10-15 minutes to output the result and if there is any faster way to calculate the number of rows?

Comment: This might help in understanding why this happens: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38027877/spark-transformation-why-its-lazy-and-what-is-the-advantage. Also, I don't think there is a faster way to get the count of the entire RDD.

Comment: @Dinosaurius: To get the count from DF , `df.count` is the only way, what you can do is, if the data is already available in file system, you could use some linux command to find the count.

Comment: how is df being created? what filter are you doing? If you provide the code for it then it would be possible to give better guesses

Comment: You should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43843470/how-to-know-which-count-query-is-the-fastest

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`df.count()` is the correct way. 
Note that `df.filter(...)` is a **transformation**, which means it is lazy, i.e. the filtering code isn't executed yet. It will only be executed if you add an **actiton** like `count` or `collect` to the filtered result. And then the runtime should be similar to the original call to `count`.